# Please elaborate the below program

Tags: python

In variable `noprimes` what is the use of declaring second `i` in `j` loop? Is it taking values from first `i` loop or referencing  `i` values?

```
>>> noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)] 
>>> primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
>>> print primes 
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

Comment: Think of it as a double `for` loop. It might be easier to understand if you read it like this: `[j for j in range(i*2, 50, i)  for i in range(2, 8)]`. Note that this is not valid Python thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as a double `for` loop. It might be easier to understand if you read it like this:

```
[j for j in range(i*2, 50, i)  for i in range(2, 8)]  # **Not valid Python!**
```

or this:

```
noprimes = []
for i in range(2, 8):
    for j in range(2 * i, 50, i):
        noprimes.append(j)
```

In the first outer loop iteration, `i` is 2 and therefore `j` runs the `range(4, 50, 2)` range. As a result, the numbers (`j`s) it produces are the following:

```
j = [4, 6, ..., 48]
```

In the next iteration, `i = 3` and the new `j`s are:

```
j = [6, 9, ..., 48]
```

And so on until `i = 7`. Finally, you put all these `j`s together creating the `noprimes` `list`.

This is simply an implementation of [Eratosthenes Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It collects all the multiples of (numbers up to 7) up to 50 and everything that is not included in there is a prime.